# Android USB Driver not installing

Tags: android

I'm trying to get my HTC Wildfire S connected to Windows 7 64-bit for dev. When it's plugged in via usb cable, Windows informs of the failure to install driver.  The HTC sync software also fails to install too.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Android sdk has some extra stuff on it containing usb drivers , also if you have any previous installed drivers usb drivers even for other phone models try to remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the complectation of your phone, maybe CDs, probably it contains needed driver.
If not try to install google oem usb driver from here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html

Comment: Downloaded the HTC Sync software a second time and disabled the Anti Virus software and it worked this time around.